# Creating a sub menu when onClick in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, submenu

I am new to react and I need help with making sub-menus. What I have so far, is a toolbar that has a square icon. What I want is when I click on this icon a sub-menu pops up below it:

Here is the code for the toolbar and the icon:

```
const toolbar = (props) => (
    <header>
        <ul className="Toolbar">
            <ul className="align-items">
                <li className="closer-to-sidebar">
                    <img src = {square} alt="square icon"/>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </header>
);
```

I just don't know how to do this and couldn't find any relevant solutions elsewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react: menu + submenu + content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149962/react-menu-submenu-content)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `material-ui` Menu. Here is an example:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

export default function SimpleMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button aria-controls="simple-menu" aria-haspopup="true" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Source](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/)